# Dialog with a counter in Android Studio

Tags: android

I have an application that performs writing by NFC on a card, depending on the number that has passed will perform a number or other reads. I guess I do this with a simple for loop, the problem is that I do not know where to put that for loop. I give you an example of the class:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(), OnClickDetailsMonuments {

    private lateinit var homeFragmentViewModel: HomeFragmentViewModel
    private lateinit var homeMonumentsAdapter: MonumentsAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        initViews()
        getObservers()
        onClickGoToMaps(view)

        homeFragmentViewModel.loadJsonFromRetrofit()

    }

    private fun onClickGoToMaps(view: View) {
        fbGoToMaps.setOnClickListener {
            view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.googleMapsMonumentsFragment)
        }
    }

    private fun getObservers() {
        viewModel.getNFCInfo().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                when(it.status){
                    AsyncResult.Status.SUCCESS -> {
                        NFCProvider.initialize(context, it.data)
                    }
                    AsyncResult.Status.ERROR -> {

                    }
                    AsyncResult.Status.LOADING -> {

                    }
                }
            })
    }

    override fun onClickFavListener(monuments: MonumentsVO) {
        homeFragmentViewModel.updateDatabaseFavoriteCheckFromViewModel(monuments.id, monuments.fav)
    }

    override fun onClickRowListenerExtras(monuments: MonumentsVO, position: Int, extras: FragmentNavigator.Extras) {
        val bundle = bundleOf(BUNDLE_MONUMENT to monuments)
        view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.detailsMonumentsFragment, bundle, null, extras)
    }

    override fun onClickRowListener(monuments: MonumentsVO, position: Int) {}

    private fun initViews() {
        homeFragmentViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeFragmentViewModel::class.java)
        rvHomeFragmentMonumentsRetrofit.setHasFixedSize(true)
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        rvHomeFragmentMonumentsRetrofit.layoutManager = layoutManager
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.show()
    }

    private fun showDialog(title: String, process: String, titleButton: String) {
        val dialog = CustomSuccessDialog(title, process, titleButton)
        dialog.show()
    }

    override onNewIntentResult(intent) {
        val message = NFCProvider.retrieveNfcMessage(intent)

        if(message) {
            showDialog("Correct reading", "1 de 4", "Continue")
        } else {
            showDialog("Error reading", "1 de 4", "Retry")
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see the problem is that when I start the NFC is when I pass the message. I get this message from an internet service and it returns the number of cards that I have to record, which is the one I have to go through, and since on the one hand I have the onNewIntent that I need for the NFC and on the other hand the observer, I don't know how to do it to put it all together and that every time I write an NFC card I get the correct dialogue and when I continue to the next one, the number of the dialogue increases: 1 of 4, 2 of 4, 3 of 4, etc. See if you can give me a hand. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the instance of the dialog and update your textView in your dialog like this:

```
if(message) {
    if(mDialog?.isShowing == false) {
        showDialog("Correct reading", "1 de 4", "Continue")
    } else {
        mDialog.updateText("$count de 4")
        count ++
    }
}
```

And your showDialog method will look something like this:

```
private fun showDialog(title: String, process: String, titleButton: String) {
    mDialog = CustomSuccessDialog(title, process, titleButton)
    mDialog.show()
}
```

Comment: The problem is that this number I have to pass on to you for you to update must be taken from the call to the service I make.

Comment: What is the problem with sending it via intent?